# MySQL SELECT WHERE LIKE escaped data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `DESTINATIONS`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `DESTINATIONS` (
  `DEST_ID` int(7) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `COUNT_ID` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `REG_ID` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `CITY_ID` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `CREATE_DATE` datetime NOT NULL,
  `DESTINATION` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `APPROVED` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`DEST_ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=192 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `DESTINATIONS`
--

INSERT INTO `DESTINATIONS` (`DEST_ID`, `COUNT_ID`, `REG_ID`, `CITY_ID`, `CREATE_DATE`, `DESTINATION`, `APPROVED`) 
VALUES (166, 9, 818, 0, '2011-10-27 15:24:20', 'Freeman\\''s Bay', 0);
```

And I am trying to run the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `DESTINATIONS` 
WHERE  `DESTINATION` LIKE  '%Freeman\'s Bay%'
```

which is returning 0 results. However, stripping the LIKE clause to anything BEFORE the quote mark will find and return a match.

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong, but I haven't been able to figure out what exactly. Can I not perform a SELECT LIKE this? Have I escaped the quotes incorrectly? Any input is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe I am causing some confusion here - the CREATE TABLE and INSERT are in a .SQL file, and it is escaped to insert `Freeman\'s Bay` into the database.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. But why do you need to store escaped data?

Comment: I am trying to store a literal quote, and not have it confused with the end of the SQL command, therefore it has to be escaped.

Comment: I know, but the backslash itself shouldn't have to be stored with it in the database. You're over escaping.

Comment: Huh. Guess so. This is probably a result of having magic_quotes on, AND being in the habit of using msql_real_escape_strings when inserting data. Interesting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>The insert is escaped incorrectly. You are actually inserting the value `Freeman\'s Bay`, including the `\`. The select is okay.</strike>

The select is escaped incorrectly. You are have inserting the value `Freeman\'s Bay`, but you're looking for `Freeman's Bay`, excluding the `\`.

Comment: Which is what I need to insert, I can't insert that single-quote unescaped??

Comment: Yes, but it's now double escaped. The double backslash is interpreted as a single backslash, and I think the two single quotes are interpreted as a single quote as well. So now, you're inserting an actual backslash in the database, which I think is not what you meant to do. You only need to escape the single quote in the INSERT statement, to make the statement valid.

Comment: `Freeman\'s Bay` is what I want to have appear in the database, and I've confirmed that is what this insert will produce. The problem is selecting this record after is has been inserted.

Comment: You will need to use the same escape sequence. You're now looking for `Freeman's Bay`, without the backslash.

Comment: Interesting - running `SELECT * FROM DESTINATIONS WHERE DESTINATION = 'Freeman\\''s Bay'` worked, but running `SELECT * FROM DESTINATIONS WHERE DESTINATION LIKE '%Freeman\\''s Bay%'` returned no results.

Comment: Try this: `SELECT * FROM DESTINATIONS WHERE DESTINATION LIKE '%Freeman\\\'s Bay%'`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM DESTINATIONS WHERE DESTINATION LIKE '%Freeman\\\'s Bay%'` didn't work, but `SELECT * FROM DESTINATIONS WHERE DESTINATION LIKE '%Freeman\\\\''s Bay%'` did. Guess I haven't been clear on when it is being parsed as a string before being parsed as a SQL query. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 1):

`'%Freeman\'s Bay%'` and  `'Freeman\\''s Bay'` are even visibly different (obviously excluding `%`). If you fixed whichever one you want to be your format you will be good

Comment: Maybe I am causing some confusion here - the CREATE TABLE and INSERT are in a .SQL file, and it is escaped to insert `Freeman\'s Bay` into the database.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try writing the LIKE string as it appears in the INSERT statement, but with a % on either end?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a repeated quote instead of escaping it? Thus: `'Freeman''s Bay'`

Use the same syntax in both places.